# What is the equivalent of Get-SMBSession in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, server-message-block

What is the equivalent of Get-SMBSession in Windows Server 2008? I am not using `Get-SMBSession` inside windows Server 2008.

thanks,

Comment: CMD command: net session

Comment: @batistuta09  thanks lastly ,  What is the equivalent of Get-SMBConnection in Windows Server 2008?

Comment: "net session"  shows SMB connections on server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/hh750729(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm on my Windows Server 2008R2:

https://github.com/proxb/PInvoke/blob/master/Get-NetSession.ps1